# How to increase the order reference length as our wish in prestashop

Tags: reference, prestashop, customization

We want to modify the order reference logic in prestashop and for that, we implemented the logic. Logic is fine. Working great but we are getting one error

```
[PrestaShopException]

Property OrderPayment->order_reference length (14) must be between 0 and 9 at line 909 in file classes/ObjectModel.php

904.             }
905. 
906.             $message = $this->validateField($field, $this->$field);
907.             if ($message !== true) {
908.                 if ($die) {
909.                     throw new PrestaShopException($message);
910.                 }
911.                 return $error_return ? $message : false;
912.             }
913.         }
914.
```

Our Length is 30. How can we increase the length from 9 to 30 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override class `OrderPayment` with this file `/override/classes/order/OrderPayment.php`:

```php
<?php
class OrderPayment extends OrderPaymentCore
{
    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null)
    {
        self::$definition['fields']['order_reference']['size'] = 30;
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang, $id_shop);
    }
}
```

Plus you'll have to update the database order_reference field size in phpmyadmin SQL tab:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `ps_order_payment`
CHANGE `order_reference`
`order_reference` VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you please accept it to mark this thread as solved? [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: The link explaining how to do this action is in the comment just above yours ;) : [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)